# Flutter Row not taking full Scaffold height

Tags: flutter, dart, row, height, scaffold

I am working on the skeleton of a tablet app with flutter and I am facing, probably a very simple issue, but it is getting tricky for me to figure out what is going on here.

Basically the skeleton of the app should look something like this:

[image]

For that, I have written a simple `Stateless` class like this:

```
class BaseDetailsRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(flex: 1, child: _selectionColumn()),
          Flexible(flex: 7, child: _contentArea())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _contentArea() => Container(color: Colors.orange,);

  Column _selectionColumn() => Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue,))
    ],
  );
}
```

Which is giving me ALMOST the expected result:

[image]

The little issue here is on the bottom of the screen, as you can see, in the `Scaffold`, I have put `backgroundColor: Colors.grey`, and, after rendering the `Row` in the screen, it seems like for some reason I cannot make it take the whole available height, and I still see a bit of the grey background color of the Scaffold on the bottom.

I have tried wrapping the whole Scaffold inside a `SafeArea` widget, but it did not work.

How can I fix this in an easy way, meaning not having to add a bunch of other widgets?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of weird but your code is working as intended on my side (For both Portrait and Landscape). What emulator are you using?

See Picture: [Pixel 2 API 29 Emulator Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCw64.png) 
[Pixel 2 API 29 Emulator Lanscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgVok.png)

Comment: ok that is good to know, I am using real device, a tablet in this case so, it it perhaps something that the tablet is producing?, very weird

Comment: no, unfortunately I just have the possibility to use one single tablet that I have now, I will try to test that on an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

could you Please try

```
     child: Column(
                mainAxisSize:  MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
```

and let me know is it working

Comment: thanks but no it does not, note that the Column is inside the main Row that is in the body of the Scaffold, so the Column "seems" to not be the problem here, I think.